# How to join mimic many to many behavior in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs, gs-vlookup

I have 2 tables in a Google Sheets file. And I need to join the tables to make a calculation:

**Example**:
[image]

In this example, I need to get the total score or sum of all reports a team is associated with.

I know I can get all the reports IDs associated with the team by using this:

```
FILTER(F2:F, E2:E = A2)
```

but I don't know what to do from there.

I'm thinking about finding all report scores whose id is in that list. and then using a Sum like this:

```
SUMIF(I2:I, (INCLUDE(H2, FILTER(F2:F, E2:E = A2))))
```

Where INCLUDE determines if a value is inside a set of elements or range.

Example with expected results: [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9ex6ngcNEOS8k_WjixnNuZrMdUyzj_PC4mBMHyN0Ys/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Here is a copy I also updated the question
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9ex6ngcNEOS8k_WjixnNuZrMdUyzj_PC4mBMHyN0Ys/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **C2** and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUM(VLOOKUP(FILTER(G:G, F:F=A2), I:J, 2, 0))))
```

[image: 0]